# how can I find out brand of a network device by knowing only MAC addr

Tags: networking, mac

I have MAC address of some networking (WiFi) devices, is there any web platform that I can search by the MAC address to find out what company they belong to?

for example, if I search for `78-DD-08`, the result will show that it belongs to `Atheros`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search the [IEEE OUI database](http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/public.html).

> Here are the results of your search through the public section of the
>   IEEE Standards OUI database report for 78-DD-08:
>
> 78-DD-08   (hex)        Hon Hai Precision Ind. Co.,Ltd.   78DD08     (base
>   16)       Hon Hai Precision Ind. Co.,Ltd.
>                     NO.1925,Nanle Road ,Songjiang Export Processing Zone
>                 Shanghai   201613
>                 CHINA

Comment: thank you. It is weird that I have Atheros AR9285 chipset and its MAC starts with 78-DD-08.

Comment: Could be re-branding.